# Is there a new way to compare to NaN in an odata filter in Azure Search after the regression in 2016-09-01-Preview?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

What is the official way to find documents that match NaN in an Edm.Double field via the rest API on version 2016-09-01-Preview and above?

Specifically we see this json post to the /search endpoint finds the document in version 2016-09-01, but not in version 2016-09-01-Preview and above.

```
{"filter":"(doublefield eq NaN)","select":"id","top":10,"skip":0,"count":true}
```

---

**Full reproduction information below**

Index definition:

```
{  
   "name":"indexnamehere",
   "fields":[  
      {  
         "name":"doublefield",
         "type":"Edm.Double",
         "searchable":false,
         "filterable":true,
         "sortable":true,
         "facetable":false,
         "key":false,
         "retrievable":true
      },
      {  
         "name":"id",
         "type":"Edm.String",
         "searchable":false,
         "filterable":true,
         "sortable":true,
         "facetable":false,
         "key":true,
         "retrievable":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Documents:

```
{  
   "value":[  
      {  
         "id":"60660cd3b9e24d26ae3609926f44aead",
         "doublefield":"NaN",
         "@search.action":"upload"
      },
      {  
         "id":"70660cd3b9e24d26ae3609926f44aead",
         "doublefield":"2",
         "@search.action":"upload"
      }
   ]
}
```

Query 1 - finds the document:

```
{"filter":"(doublefield eq 2)","select":"id","top":10,"skip":0,"count":true}
```

Query 2 - fails to find the document (in 2016-09-01-Preview and above):

```
{"filter":"(doublefield eq NaN)","select":"id","top":10,"skip":0,"count":true}
```

ps. this is our current work around `not(doubleField ge -INF) and doubleField ne null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with API version 2016-09-01-Preview, Azure Search now implements the IEEE 754 semantics for comparisons with `NaN`, per the [clarified](https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-1032) [OData V4.01 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_Equals).

> The special value NaN is not equal to anything, even to itself.

Prior to this, `NaN` comparisons were unreliable. In particular, the inequality operators did not behave correctly, or even consistently between different Search services.

We made this change on an API version boundary to avoid breaking existing applications, but going forward applications using version 2016-09-01-Preview or later cannot detect `NaN` in double fields. If you need to have some kind of sentinel value for `Edm.Double` fields, we recommend using `null` instead since you can check for `null` with filters.

Allowing `NaN` to be indexed has turned out to be problematic, and we're considering disallowing it altogether in a future API version.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. One of the more problematic cases is when implementing general scaning all documents with the work around mentioned here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.skip?view=azure-dotnet, combined with free selection of the sorting keys. The problem being that if one of the keys is a double and there is more than a page's worth of NaN, then one can't get the next page without skipping results i.e. as one needs to do (doublefield eq NaN and otherfield > lastValueOfPage). FWIW we hit it only with test datasets.

Comment: Any chance of adding a function equivalent to .net's double.IsNaN would be added? i.e. in .net NaN is not equal to itself, but one can then use that method to do the comparison, which does not contradict the spec.

Comment: It wouldn't be easy given our general issues around NaN, but you can always open a User Voice item (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search). If it becomes a popular request, we'll consider it. However, given that this is the first time we've encountered a real scenario for this, and the scenario is to workaround the skip limitation, I'd say it's more likely we'll address the skip limitation than NaN query support.